# "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" error when returning a row in SQLite DB

Tags: swift, sqlite, fmdb

I have integrated the FMDB Sqlite Wrapper into my iOS application and I have written a couple of DB functions, that have all worked perfectly until now.

I used the same approach for a simple method that is supposed to return a single element in a Resultset item, but I get the above error. There is nothing different in the logic from the other methods so I have no idea why the error occurs and why it happens on both lines with stringForColumn and not in the line with intForColumn (as the debugger tells me).

Any help or tips would be greatly appreciated!

```
func fetchExercise(exerciseId: Int) -> Exercise {
    sharedInstance.database!.open()
    let resultSet: FMResultSet! = sharedInstance.database!.executeQuery("Select * from Exercises where ExerciseId = ?", withArgumentsInArray: [String(exerciseId)])
    let fetchedExercise: Exercise = Exercise()
    if (resultSet != nil) {
        fetchedExercise.exerciseId = Int(resultSet.intForColumn("ExerciseId"))
        fetchedExercise.exerciseCategory = resultSet.stringForColumn("ExerciseCategory")
        fetchedExercise.exerciseTitle = resultSet.stringForColumn("ExerciseTitle")
    }
    sharedInstance.database!.close()
    return fetchedExercise      
}
```

The `resultSet` is as follows:

[image]

Comment: set a breakpoint and show us the values of the resultSet before the failure.

Comment: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=vqn0cw&s=9#.VsEryRjrKCQ
I don't know how to interpret this, could you explain? I checked for the other DB functions and it's also empty when I open ObjectiveC.NSObject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call `resultsSet.next()` to retrieve the results. For example:

```
func fetchExercise(exerciseId: Int) -> Exercise {
    sharedInstance.database!.open()
    defer { sharedInstance.database!.close() }

    let resultSet = try! sharedInstance.database!.executeQuery("Select * from Exercises where ExerciseId = ?", values: [exerciseId])
    let fetchedExercise = Exercise()
    if resultSet.next() {
        fetchedExercise.exerciseId       = resultSet.longForColumn("ExerciseId")
        fetchedExercise.exerciseCategory = resultSet.stringForColumn("ExerciseCategory")
        fetchedExercise.exerciseTitle    = resultSet.stringForColumn("ExerciseTitle")
    }

    return fetchedExercise
}
```

BTW, I'm not sure why you're converting `exerciseId` to a string in the query. I'd personally just pass the `Int` value, as shown above.

Comment: Thank you very much! This fixed the problem.